# pass request for authentication to backend server before serving cache in haproxy

Tags: authentication, caching, varnish, haproxy

Currently we are using HAProxy for load-balancing, but we are thinking to use it for API data caching also along with Varnish. As far as I have investigate I have came across that we can validate a request for cache using HTTPBasicAuthentication

```
if (! req.http.Authorization ~ "Basic Zm9vOmJhcgo=")
{
  error 401 "Restricted";
}
```

But my authentication is dynamic, I need to check my db whether this request is valid or not. SO this thing wont work for me. What I am looking is
[image]

In my `Validate The Request` I want to pass the request to my backend server and if it returns 200 I want to go forward and check the data in my cache otherwise return `Unauthorised access`. Let me know the way to implement this

Answer (score 1):

You can authorise requests in Varnish. There are enough VMODs to implement that easily: cURL, Digest, Redis/Memcache/..., etc (see https://www.varnish-cache.org/vmods). That approach is the basic idea behind products like Varnish Paywall or the recently presented Varnish API Engine.